# How to use conditional WHERE in raw queries like in eloquent

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

This is more of a theoretical question. How can you use conditions in a raw laravel query like you do when using eloquent? With simple queries this is not a problem as you can write the query in eloquent but with more complex queries, this would be a nice feature to have (I'm unsure whether it exists or not).

Here is a very simple example. The Eloquent version works but the raw version won't. If this were to be done using a raw query, how would you do it?

**Eloquent...**

```php
$query = Transaction::orderBy('processingTime', 'desc');

if(isset($request->search['status'])) {
   $query->where('status', '=', $request->search['status']);
}

$query->get();
```

**Raw...**

```php
$query = DB::select('SELECT * FROM transactions ORDER BY processingTime DESC');

if(isset($request->search['status'])) {
   $query->where('status', '=', $request->search['status']);
}

$query->get();
```

The reason I'm asking this question is because I was facing this problem yesterday with a complex query and managed to solve it using collections but I can't help thinking there is an easier more efficient way of doing this. Here's how I solved it last night.

```php
$report = collect(DB::connection('mysql2')->select("SELECT
            t2.holder,
            t2.merchantTransactionId,
            t2.bin,
            t2.last4Digits,
            t3.expDate,
            (CASE WHEN t3.expDate < CURDATE() THEN 'Expired'
            WHEN t3.expDate > CURDATE() THEN 'Due to expire' END) AS expInfo,
            t2.uuid
            FROM transactions AS t2
            INNER JOIN (
                SELECT t1.uuid, t1.holder, t1.bin, t1.last4Digits, LAST_DAY(CONCAT(t1.expiryYear, t1.expiryMonth, '01')) AS expDate
                FROM transactions t1
                JOIN (SELECT t1.merchant_access
                        FROM total_control.users, 
                        JSON_TABLE(merchant_access, '$[*]' COLUMNS (
                            merchant_access VARCHAR(32) PATH '$')
                        ) t1
                        WHERE users.id = :userId
                        ) AS t2
                    ON t1.merchantUuid = t2.merchant_access
                WHERE t1.paymentType = 'RG'
                AND t1.status = 1
            ) t3
            ON t2.uuid = t3.uuid
            WHERE t3.expDate BETWEEN DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 30 DAY) AND DATE_ADD(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 30 DAY)
            GROUP BY t2.holder, t2.bin, t2.last4Digits
            ORDER BY t2.holder ASC", ['userId' => $request->userId]));

if(isset($request->search['holder'])) {
    $filtered = $report->filter(function($value, $key) use ($request) {
        if(strpos(strtolower($value->holder), strtolower($request->search['holder'])) !== false) {
            return $value;
        }
    });
    return $filtered->all();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can refer to the documentation for more details [query builder](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/queries#where-clauses)

you can also use raw expression to make complex conditions. [Raw Expressions](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/queries#raw-expressions)

```
$query = Transaction::orderBy('processingTime', 'desc');

if(isset($request->search['status'])) {
   $query->where(DB::raw("status= $request->search['status']"));
}

$query->get();
```

As you can see from below query i have use it in one of my query.

```
$query->where(DB::raw("str_to_date(supplier_bookings.created_at, '%Y-%m-%d')"), [$from, $to]);
```

Note: Raw statements will be injected into the query as strings, so you should be extremely careful to not create SQL injection vulnerabilities.

furthermore you can also use **whereRaw** method

```
    $query = Transaction::orderBy('processingTime', 'desc');

if(isset($request->search['status'])) {
   $query->whereRaw("status= $request->search['status']");
}

$query->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

When you do a `DB::select()` it runs the query directly, Use `DB::table()` instead to instantiate a query builder.

```
$query = DB::table('transactions')->orderBy('processingTime', 'desc');

if(isset($request->search['status'])) {
    $query->where('status', '=', $request->search['status']);
}

$query->get();
```

Comment: I already know that mate but with simple queries, that's easy to do. Look at my third example, it's much more complicated hence why I've written it out all raw using DB::select. How can I use conditions on a query like that?

Comment: The 3rd (complicated) example can't be run in `STRICT MODE`, value of the fields `t2.merchantTransactionId`, `t3.expDate` and `t2.uuid` will be random in non strict mode. Since the query itself in not correct, it will be hazardous/impossible to do a query builder for it.

Answer (score 0):

I have run through situations like this in my projects. I simply start a query string and then add conditions to it with simple concatenation as I go and the run the query altogether at the end.

Not sure if it's possible for your complex query but for your simple example, you could follow the same method like so (following your style):

```
$query = 'SELECT * FROM transactions';
$orderBy = ' ORDER BY processingTime DESC';

if (isset($request->search['status'])) {
    $query .= ' WHERE status = '.$request->search['status'];
}

$query .= $orderBy;
$query = DB::select($query);
$query->get();
```

Of course, you need to be creative based upon what you need. For example if you needed multiple where with AND, you could do something like:

```
$query = 'SELECT * FROM transactions';
$orderBy = ' ORDER BY processingTime DESC';

$where = [1];
if ($condition1) {
    $where[] = 'condition1 = '.$condition1;
}
if ($condition2) {
    $where[] = 'condition2 = '.$condition2;
}
$where = implode(' AND ', $where);

$query .= ' WHERE '.$where;
$query .= $orderBy;

$query = DB::select($query);
$query->get();
```

*I hope it helps*

Comment: Thanks @Learner, not the answer I was looking for in the sense that I was hoping there would be an easier way to do this but I appreciate the fact that you fully understood my question :-)

Comment: of course, voted +1, it would be nice to have something like that inbuild into Laravel but then again that would be eloquent so there is that. Myself, cant think of any other way of using mysql raw queries with conditions inside laravel. Just the good old PHP way lol.

Comment: It's annoying because it's not realistic to write all queries in eloquent. Some are just far too complex and it's time consuming even trying to convert normal SQL queries into eloquent queries. It would be great if you can mix pure raw queries with eloquent.

Comment: couldn't agree more, i also go with raw sql when i see its starting to get so complex. Also it helps me debug it faster as i can just copy paste it to phpmyadmin, rather than dumping toSql()